# Transfer settings from Windows 2003 to a new server

Tags: windows, migration, windows-server-2003

I would like to transfer the maximum amount of settings from one win2003 server to a new one (servers have different hardware configurations). At least, I need Group Policies, Local Security Policies, User Accounts. It will be better if I could transfer installed applications and some dirictories, including their NTFS privilegies.

What is the better solution for this task?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use full disk backup software that allows restores to dissimilar hardware. Most major backup vendors support backup to dissimilar hardware, so choose something that you're familiar with and call their sales department and confirm that it will work.